# Chrome extension not showing background image in new tab on install

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension which changes the background image of a new tab. The first time I load the extension the background image doesn't change.

This problem also **very occasionally** arises after using it for long periods of time (but I'm not sure at what times it doesn't work except on first install). Thanks.

**main.js**

```
    /*THIS CODE IS FOR GETTING THE NUMBER OF IMAGES FROM PHP*/

   // INCLUDE JQUERY LIBRARY: OTHERWISE THIS WON'T WORK...
   // SURE YOU CAN ALSO DO ALL THESE IN PURE JAVASCRIPT, BUT WHY RE-INVENT THE WHEEL? :-)

   (function ($) {
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
           $.ajax({
               url: 'http://url.com/numberOfImages.php',     // <== CHANGE URL
               dataType: "HTML",
               cache: false,
               type: "POST",

               //HANDLE THE SUCCESS CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
               success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   if(data){
                       localStorage.numberOfImages = data;
                       gotNumberOfImages = true;

                   }
               },

               //HANDLE THE FAILURE CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
               error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   console.log('The following error occurred: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
               },

               //HANDLE THE EVENT-COMPLETE CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
               complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
               }
           });
       });
   })(jQuery);






   window.onload = function() {
     showNewImage();
     var str = document.getElementById("greet").innerHTML;
     var res = str.replace("\'\'", " " + localStorage.name); // replace with name
     document.getElementById("greet").innerHTML = res;
   };



// Set up the image files to be used.
var theImages = new Array() // do not change this
// To add more image files, continue with the
// pattern below, adding to the array.


var numberOfImages;
if (navigator.onLine) { //checking if connected to internet, if it finds the user is online it'll call the images that are on the server.
  for(i = 0; i<=localStorage.numberOfImages;i++){
    theImages[i] = 'http://url.com/images/'+ i +'.jpg'; //NAME THE IMAGES ON THE SERVER 0.JPG, 1.JPG, 2.JPG and so on.
  }
} else { //if offline, if it finds that the user is offline it'll use these images. REMEMBER TO PUT A FEW OF THESE.
  theImages[0] = 'image3.jpg'
  theImages[1] = 'image4.jpg'
}





var j = 0
var p = theImages.length;
var preBuffer = new Array()
for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
   preBuffer[i] = new Image()
   preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
}
var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
function showNewImage(){
document.body.style['background-image'] = 'url("' + theImages[whichImage] + '")';
//localStorage.img = theImages[whichImage];
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "App name",
  "description": "Add description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "main.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "some title"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**main.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>New Tab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/octicons/octicons.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
...
    <script src = "main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the window is already loaded when you load the extension, it won't work because   `showNewImage()` is triggered by `window.onload` in line 1.

add   `showNewImage();` a second time to the end of your script like this:

```
    document.body.style['background-image'] = 'url("' + theImages[whichImage] + '")';
    //localStorage.img = theImages[whichImage];
    }
    showNewImage();
```

This will run the script when the extension is first loaded.

Comment: nope, still not showing. What else can I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps, by including "persistent":false in your manifest (which creates an event page - see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), the script is not running continuously in the background as you wish. Try "persistent":true?

Comment: I've tried it. Still when I load the package it doesn't show an image the first time.

Comment: The background script is utterly useless, `persistent` or not, since it only contains a copy jQuery that no other script can use.

Comment: @Xan - you're right. @Ron - one last stab - The anonymous function to load pictures includes `$(document).ready(function(e) {`, so if the document is already ready when the extension is loaded, it won't be fired. Try removing `$(document).ready(function(e) {`

Comment: @grateful still doesn't load the image the **first** time I install/load it. Any other suggestions? Also, do you see any other occurrences where this error  may arise?

Comment: Have you tried both the first suggestion      "add  showNewImage(); a second time to the end of your script"      and the third      "Try removing $(document).ready(function(e) {"     together?

Comment: @Xan do you have a solution?

Comment: I suppose I do in a manner of speaking. Your AJAX request happens asynchronously, so by the time you try to use `localStorage.numberOfImages` it's not set yet. You should read the question I linked and adapt the logic accordingly - not do anything until the AJAX request succeeds or fails.

Comment: @Xan Thanks so much. I completely understand your answer/solution but I'm still not being able to implement it in my code. Could you please help? I've tried everything I could think of.